# Programmatically fill a column with year-month values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

How to programmatically fill a table column with year-month values?

This is the aim:

```
DATE
2014-12
2014-11
2014-10
..
2014-02
2014-01
2013-12
2013-11
```

Etc., back to a set date e.g. `2008-01`

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - PHP

Comment: 1) loops 2) insert queries.

Comment: Is it good practice to use SQL queries in loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and just loop over the years and months:

```
$START_YEAR = 2008;
$END_YEAR = 2012;
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', $username, $password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?)");
for ($year = START_YEAR; $year <= END_YEAR; ++$year) {
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; ++$month) {
        $stmt->bindParam (1, "${year}-${month}");
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```